# function does not exist .. in phpMyAdmin mysql Query

Tags: mysql, function

This query returns 7

```
SELECT datediff('20130510', '20130503')
```

but This query returns error
error string is function datediff does not exist

```
SELECT datediff(to_dt, from_dt) FROM `tbl_test`
```

I don't know the reason 
please help me..

Comment: what data type are to_dt and from_dt

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I created a table `Date` on one of my phpmyadmin databases, just to see how this query works.

My table has 2 columns, date_of_birth and date_of_death, both of type date.
I inserted some 5 or 6 tuples. And after that typed in this query:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date_of_birth, date_of_death) FROM Date;
```

It worked just fine. Gave me 7,53, 365, 733...ergo, the correct results, without any error.

I think there is something wrong in your database.

Comment: I could find some comments for this problem by google search.
may be mysql bug..

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14124

this query did not return error..
SELECT datediff(to_dt, from_dt) FROM `tbl_test`  limit 0, 10 

I intend to use datediff function with limit clause